# Nativescript: how to turn off predictions for textField on android?

Tags: android, typescript, native, nativescript

So I am writing my app in typescript and I want to disable predictions which appear when you are typing something in input. I want to disable them even if they are enabled on the device. I get the reference to my input (textField) element like this, which works:

`this.page.getViewById("place")`

In nativescript documentation I don't see an option to turn off predictions programmatically, but I do know it can be done through native functions (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) with `setInputType` method and passing a flag `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`.

So I access the native function like this:

```
var input_type = new android.text.InputType("TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS");

this.page.getViewById("place").android.setInputType( input_type );
```

But I guess I am initializing the InputType class incorrectly, because it throws an error:

`First argument must be implementation object`

Comment: TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS is an integer ... check in documentation the value and use it ...

Comment: Ah, you are right. Changed `InputType("TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS")` to `InputType(524288)`, but getting the same error.

Comment: Also tried `setInputType(524288)` which didn't work.

Comment: TextField has property `autocorrect` -  http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html#autocorrect. You could set this property to `false` and predictions should stop

Comment: android.text.InputType is an interface, hence why you are getting that error.

Comment: Not sure what `autocorrect` does, but it certainly doesn't disable predictions. `this.page.getViewById<textFieldModule.TextField>("place").autocorrect = false;`

Comment: Ok, autocorrect actually does disable autocorrection - if you type "Ca" and press space, it won't get autocorrected to "Can". However, I still see the suggestion window above keyboard, which I need to remove programmatically. How do I do it?

Comment: @Starwave did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to find an iOS solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, for the love of God, finally worked with this:

```
this.page.getViewById<textFieldModule.TextField>("place").android.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with ios?

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend @Starwave solution, you can set (loaded) event on TextField and then inside trigger disabling suggestions like this

```
onTextFieldLoaded(args) {
  let textfield: TextField = <TextField>args.object;
  if (isAndroid) {
    textfield.android.setInputType(
      android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | 
      android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
    );
  }
}
```